# How to say a city has a polluted air properly?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I was wondering if you could let me know which one of the  following sentences is the natural way to say it:

> - **This city's weather is so polluted.** (To my non-native ear, it sounds to be the most correct one)
>
>   - **This city's air is so polluted.** (I don't know if "air" works in this sense)
>   - **This city's is so polluted.** (I think witout mentioning "weather" it would be ambiguous)
>   - **The weather in this city is so polluted.** (to me it sounds like the second version of the sentence #1)

Comment: It's common to speak of polluted air (referring to the quality of the air people breathe) and of polluted cities (with reference to pollution of any kind). I have never heard anyone speak of polluted weather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say that the **air** is polluted.  This means that the air in the city is full of unpleasant or toxic gases and particles.

You can say that that **city** is polluted. This means that the city itself (the streets, rivers and perhaps air) are full of waste or toxins.

You **cannot** say that the weather is polluted. Weather is an abstract phenomenon. (There might be metaphorical senses where you might use weather, but I can't think of one).

So, "*this city's air is so polluted*" is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Your second choice, "This city's air is so polluted," is the best option. We don't think of "weather" (rain, snow, sunshine, etc.) as being subject to pollution, and you are correct that saying the city itself was polluted (option #3) would include the soil and also rivers, lakes, etc., not just the air.